# Set Theoretic Union Symbol becomes a Logical conjunction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Often in mathematical logic I encounter the union symbol, for instance in this theorem:
$\Sigma \cup \{T\} \vDash B$ $\iff$ $\Sigma \vDash T \to B$. I am interested specifically in the term: $\Sigma \cup \{T\}$.

1. Can I translate it right into $\sigma \land T$ if we assume $\sigma \in \Sigma$ (and we assume that $\Sigma$ is a set with propositions)? I am a little bit worried because the union is usually the set theoretical equivalent of a disjunction, but here out of a union we get a logical conjunction.
2. I think that translating directly from $\Sigma \cup \{T\}$ to $\Sigma \land T$ is false because "$\land$" can only connect propositions while $\Sigma$ is a set of propostions (with precisely one proposition $\sigma$ per our assumption). Am I right?
3. If $\Sigma$ is a set of plain elements like numbers then we cannot translate it to a logical conjunction (or any other connective) in any way. Right?

Comment: To 3): yes... but $\Sigma$ is a set of formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Why into $\Sigma \cup \{ T \}$] set-theoretic union symbol becomes a logical conjunction.

$Σ$ is a *set* of formulas and $T$ is a formula; thus we use $\{ T \}$ to denote the set containing the formula $T$ and consequently we use *union* to denote the new set with all formulas of $Σ$ and $T$ as elements.

> I think that translating directly from $Σ \cup \{ T \}$ to $Σ ∧ T$ is false.

You are right. Assuming that $Σ$ is a *finite* set of formulas: $\{ σ_1, \ldots,σ_n \}$, the condition $\Sigma \cup \{ T \}$ is "equivalent" to: $σ_1 ∧ \ldots ∧ σ_n ∧ T$.

But the relevant issue is that the above result does not need that $Σ$ be a *finite* set; in case of an infinite one, we cannot use *conjunction* because in standard logic a formula is a finite length expression.